# Passing array by reference in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

this might sound a very basic question, however i am having little confusing understanding this piece of code:

so i have a function that takes argument: `const char * str1`
Now that argument passed is defined as: `const char (&str1)[5]`

I would appreciate if you could elaborate a little how the character pointer array is defined in 2nd line?

EDIT:

```
template<unsigned N, unsigned M>
int compare(const char (&p1)[N], const char (&p2)[M]){
   return strcmp(p1,p2);
}
```

I am trying to understand how the non type parameter which is essentially translating to character string is defined here

Comment: Could you show the actual function prototype and the call site? It isn't clear exactly what you mean.

Comment: It's not a character pointer array, it's a reference to an array of `char`.

Comment: @molbdnilo, thank you, so where ever we need pointer to array, we can pass array by reference??

Comment: @Jason No, that function only accepts arrays, not pointers to arrays. Remember that arrays are not pointers. This templating method is a way of writing functions that can handle arrays of different lengths without having to pass the length as a function parameter, as you would have to do in C.

Comment: ok i get it know. I was thinking whenever we pass an array even with its name, it is essentially a pointer pointing to first element of that array. as standard arrays can not be copied, but here we are using reference so its different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is "essentially translating". The function template expects to be called with two array arguments.

```
char s[] = { 'a', 0, 'c' };

compare(s, "xyz");    //  first argument "s" is a named array, N = 3
                      //  second argument is a string literal, M = 4
```

You can use the same pattern for *any* array, but the special benefit for char-like arrays is that you can have literal arrays in the form of string literals.

Comment: so char A[5] is the same as char (&A)[5] ??

Comment: @Jason: No. Do you know what references are? Values can bind to references. A value of type `char[5]` can bind to a reference of type `char(&)[5]`.

Comment: oh thank you for explanation, i am learning! its just the syntax sounds a bit confusing to me